# Every alternate Paypal IPN transaction is failing (HTTP code 400)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a weird issue with Paypal IPN. Every alternate transaction is failing. So let's say if first transactions goes well then second one fails. Similarly if 3rd one goes well then 4th one fails.
HTTP status code I am getting for failed transactions in IPN history is 400.
I have implemented the new Paypal host header changes that were newly introduced by them.

Any idea why this is happening?

**IPN History**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRiqU.png

**IPN Detail**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j31xS.png

**EDIT**
I am using PHP with curl to do IPN work (using same sample code as available on Paypal website)

**ANOTHER EDIT**
Ok I found another code sample for PHP 5.2 from Paypal site. This one is slightly different than the one I am currently using. I tested it on Paypal Sandbox twice and it worked. Later on I will test it on live to see if it is working fine or not.

Comment: Hi Frank, If you need a coding answer, you should include a code sample which reproduces this issue.

Comment: I have added some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 = bad request, this means that the get requests being made on the application layer (by your browser) may contain errors or the transport layer (syn, syn, ack, syn) 3 way hand shack is being interrupted. I would check your PC for Mallware to be on the safe side. Do a netstat -b in dos and see what's trying to get connections to the external network.

Also do a scan with malware bytes and a good virus scanner like Eset nod32.. Let us know how you get on^^

Comment: Are you using the application layer frame work? (Api), also could you have put something specific (server address) rather then a needed variable? I ask as you state that it succeeds some times and others not.

Comment: I will test the new script later today to see how it goes. Someone told me this problem is caused by .htaccess but I am not sure about it. Strange thing is if it works the first time, why doesn't it work 2nd time. Paypal checked and said that there is no problem with our script or anything.

Answer (score 0):

The new script I downloaded from Paypal website fixed the issue.